# Display a menu item with Login requirement

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu-item, login

I have made a Menu item and set its type to a 'Single Article'. I want that menu item to be displayed publically but login after clicking it to enter that article.

When I have set the access level to 'Registered', the menu link is showed to registered users only.How would I do that?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: No, I am doing some other work, so this one is pending for now.

Answer (score 1):

You should do exactly what you want to.

What you want to? You want to:

1. allow users see the link

So you should set menu item as public;

2. you want to allow to read article only to registered users

So you should set article access to registered only;

Comment: I am sorry but from where I set the point 1.?

Comment: At the creation of menu item.

Comment: and it can be changed in the edit screen